# How to check if a CLOB column has a non ASCII charatcer?

Tags: oracle, clob, non-ascii-characters

I have a table `EMPLOYEE` with a column called `LAYOUT`. `LAYOUT` is a `CLOB` column

How can I check if the `LAYOUT` contains any characters that are not ASCII? Ideally I would like to see the rows that contain the non-ASCII character

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50914930/find-out-if-a-string-contains-only-ascii-characters `CONVERT` works even with CLOB

Comment: I'm not saying you do but I see the terms "ASCII" and "Unicode" misused often. It'd be interesting to know your ultimate goal in case there's a more direct approach.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - I was unable to get the `CONVERT` method to work. I'm getting a inconsistent datatype error when selecting

`select *
from employee
where layout != CONVERT(layout, 'US7ASCII');`

Comment: Strange, according [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions041.htm#SQLRF00620) `CLOB` is supported as input and output. Perhaps you have to process chucks of your CLOB in a loop.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - Putting it into a loop did the trick. No errors there

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure it out with the help of comments on the question

```
Begin
    for empData in (select * from EMPLOYEE)
    LOOP
        IF CONVERT(empData.LAYOUT, 'US7ASCII') != empData.LAYOUT THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Non ASCII found!');
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
```