# how to know if the text is arabic or english in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

lets say i have a table like that

```
table:
C1
ابي
امي
mo
```

i want to specify the arabic and english words so i want my select to be like that

```
C1 C2
ابي Ar
امي Ar
mo EN
```

so how can i do something like that?

Comment: What output do you expect on mixed data? And if other scripts (Greek, Russian...) are found?

Comment: No its only English or arabic i just want to mark the English rows and the arabic rows

Comment: Poor man's solution is to use [REGEXP_LIKE()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm) to look for English letters (there aren't too many). It isn't a valid general solution but it should work for you.

Comment: I don't think your question is really "is text arabic or english". I guess you are more interested in the characters. Have a look at [Find out if a string contains only ASCII characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50914930/find-out-if-a-string-contains-only-ascii-characters)

Answer (score 1):

Use `TRANSLATE` or `REGEXP_LIKE` with a `CASE` expression. Assuming that your English words only contain alphabetic characters, hyphens or apostrophes then:

```sql
SELECT c1,
       CASE
       WHEN TRANSLATE(
              c1,
              '0abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-''',
              '0'
            ) IS NULL
       THEN 'EN'
       ELSE 'AR'
       END AS c2
FROM   table_name;
```

or using `REGEXP_LIKE` (which may be less to type but is likely to be less efficient):

```sql
SELECT c1,
       CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(c1, '^[a-zA-Z''-]+$') THEN 'EN' ELSE 'AR' END
         AS c2
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (c1) AS
SELECT 'ابي' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'امي' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'mo' FROM DUAL
```

Both output:

| C1 | C2 |
| --- | --- |
| ابي | AR |
| امي | AR |
| mo | EN |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/dnNG218o)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use `REGEXP_LIKE` to search for the [arabic unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_alphabet#Unicode) range 0600-06FF :

```
SELECT c1, CASE WHEN regexp_like(c1, UNISTR('[\0600-\06FF]')) THEN 'AR' ELSE 'EN' END AS c2
FROM mytable
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/0SCLoE36)

Answer (score 0):

If it is only english and arabic then the simpliest way is to get use of the fact that arabic letters are multibyte characters. You can compare length in characters with length in bytes to distinguish them:

```sql
-- Answer updated after comment below (thanks p3consulting)
WITH    -- Sample Data:
    tbl AS
        (   Select 1 "ID", 'ابي' "C1" From Dual Union All
            Select 2, 'امي' From Dual Union All
            Select 3, 'اسم عملة الاتحاد الأوروبي هو اليورو والعلامة هي €' From Dual Union All
            Select 4, 'Name of EU currency is euro and the sign is €' From Dual )
Select ID, Length(C1) "LEN", LengthB(C1) "LEN_BYTES" From tbl
/* 
        ID        LEN  LEN_BYTES
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          3          6
         2          3          6
         3         49         91
         4          2          2 */
 
Select  C1, 
        -- if there are some multibyte characters in english text (like €) then
        -- case expression in next line will give false result for english text (it would say Arabic)
        Case When Length(C1) != LengthB(C1) Then 'Arabic' Else 'English' End "LANG",
        -- This (case below) should solve the above issue (if exists)
        -- case when char length increased 70% is still less than byte length then ARABIC
        -- 70% is arbitrary - you could define it differently
        Case When Length(C1) * 1.7 < LengthB(C1) Then 'ARABIC' Else 'ENGLISH' End "LANG_2"
From tbl
/*
C1                                                  LANG    LANG_2
--------------------------------------------------  ------- -------
ابي                                                 Arabic  ARABIC
ابي                                                 Arabic  ARABIC
اسم عملة الاتحاد الأوروبي هو اليورو والعلامة هي €      Arabic  ARABIC
Name of EU currency is euro and the sign is €       Arabic  ENGLISH */
```

This should be significantly faster than regexp...

Comment: The £ character is multibyte ;) (and the € too...)

Comment: @p3consulting You are right. Didn't think about it. Just posted an update. Thanks.

Comment: Neither £ nor € belong to English alphabet. Don't forget that this question is strictly about telling English-letters-only and Arabic-letters-only strings apart. If we aim to build a general purpose solution to classify texts, we'll need to handle mixed data and every possible edge case.